# Get value array data from html to JavaScript at Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, laravel-5

I want to make a function in js where js takes value from data array html

I'm using Laravel 5.8, I want, when the button is clicked, data array is called and placed into a new form input

```
<div class="row">
  @foreach ($product as $p)
    <div class="col-md-2 stock ml-4 mt-3">
       <div class="mt-1">
          <a onclick="addlist()"> <img height="50px" class="img-thumbnail"
           src="{{ url('/product_image/'.$p->thumbnail) }}">
              <p id="qty">{{$p->qty}}</p>
              <p id="code">{{$p->code}}</p>
          </a>
       </div>
     </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

```
<div class="row">
   <input type="text" id="qtylist">
   <input type="text" id="codelist">
</div>
```

```
<script>
function addlist(){ 
    var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
    var code = document.getElementById('code').value;

   for(var i=0; i>qty.length; i++){
     var qtyList = qty[i];
     var codeList = code[i]
     document.getElementById('qtylist').value = qtyList
     document.getElementById('codelist').value = codeList
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'data array is called and placed into a new form input`, it doesn't make a lot of sense. It perhaps would be better if you told us the exact output you're trying to create

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
  @foreach ($product as $p)
    <div class="col-md-2 stock ml-4 mt-3">
       <div class="mt-1">
          <a onclick="addlist('{{$p->id}}')"> <img height="50px" class="img-thumbnail"
           src="{{ url('/product_image/'.$p->thumbnail) }}">
              <p id="{{$p->id}}-qty">{{$p->qty}}</p>
              <p id="{{$p->id}}-code">{{$p->code}}</p>
          </a>
       </div>
     </div>
  @endforeach
</div>

<script>
function addlist(i){ 
    var qty = document.getElementById(''+i+'-qty').value;
    var code = document.getElementById(''+i+''-code').value;

    document.getElementById('qtylist').value = qty;
    document.getElementById('codelist').value = code;

}
</script>
```

Note: if you want to create more then 2 input , you should use foreach loop and pass a index of each input element values.